# Player and Blocks collision (Terraria)

Tags: java

I am creating a game like Terraria. I already have a player and I can place blocks and delete them by clicking on an existing block. But I can´t figure out how to make player and block collision. I want to create physics like in terraria. Can you help me somehow?
Here are my 3 classes (I have 4 but the 4. class is only JFrame class):

Here is my Main Class (gameloop):

```
package Package;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

    Timer gameLoop = new Timer(5, this);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 900;
    public static final Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Player player = new Player();

    public static ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();

    private int xDistance;
    private int yDistance;

    public Game() {
        setPreferredSize(windowSize);
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.WIDTH; i += 50) {
            for (int j = Game.HEIGHT - 150; j < Game.HEIGHT; j += 50) {
                blocks.add(new Block(i, j));
            }
        }
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        gameLoop.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        gameLoop.stop();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        for (Block b : blocks) {
            b.render(g);
        }

        player.render(g);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        player.move();
        player.offScreen();

        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        boolean foundBlock = false;

        xDistance = mouseX % 50;
        yDistance = mouseY % 50;

        for (Block b : blocks) {
            if (b.x == mouseX - xDistance && b.y == mouseY - yDistance) {
                if (mouseX >= player.x - 150 && mouseX <= player.x + 200 && mouseY >= player.y - 150 && mouseY <= player.y + 250) {
                    blocks.remove(b);
                    foundBlock = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundBlock == false) {
            if (mouseX >= player.x - 150 && mouseX <= player.x + 200 && mouseY >= player.y - 150 && mouseY <= player.y + 250) {
                blocks.add(new Block(mouseX - xDistance, mouseY - yDistance));
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}



    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int arrows = e.getKeyCode();

        if (arrows == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            player.xSpeed = 2;
        }
        if (arrows == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            player.xSpeed = -2;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int arrows = e.getKeyCode();

        if (arrows == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            player.xSpeed = 0;
        }
        if (arrows == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            player.xSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Player class:

```
package Package;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {

    public int x = 14 * 50;
    public int y = Game.HEIGHT - (5 * 50);
    public int xSpeed = 0;
    public int ySpeed = 0;
    public boolean jump = false;
    public int ticks = 6;

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 100);
    }

    public void move() {
        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;
    }

    public void offScreen() {
        if (x <= 0) {
            xSpeed = 0;
    } else if (x + 50 >= Game.WIDTH) {
            xSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Block Class:

```
package Package;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Block {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Block(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is *extremely broad*, please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) containing what you wrote to accomplish your goal and the exact difficulty you face.

Comment: "physics like in terraria" might not be as descriptive as you think. Please explain exactly what you're trying to do for people who have never played this game.

Comment: I want to make player and block collision. The system of collisions.

Comment: I second the points made above, and in addition report a side issue: your Game class extends JPanel and both overrides its `paint` method and does not call the super `paint` method within the override, something that will break the painting chain. Much better to override `paintComponent` not `paint`, and to be sure to call the `.super.paintComponent(...)` method within this override.

Comment: Other issues: favor key bindings over KeyLIsteners, and try to separate differing concerns, often by using a Model-View-Controller set up. This way, the game logic can be encapsulated in your Model, and since it would be held within a separately testable unit of code, this will make it much easier for you to create your [mcve] for any questions or problems you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to store you blocks this way:

```
public static ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
```

Instead, create a structure that easily allows you to access blocks by their coordinates.  Maybe:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Block>>()
```

... where the 1st Integer is the X coordinate and the 2nd is the Y.  That way, you can quickly find the blocks that have *any* chance of colliding with the player, instead of checking every block in the world every iteration.

Also, why is this `static`?  It shouldn't be, I think.

To check for collisions (I assume to prevent players from moving through blocks), just figure out the coordinates of where the player would wind up after the proposed move and see if the players bounding rectangle (the rectangle from the upper left of the player's sprite to the lower right) overlaps the bounding rectangle of any block.

But it's really important: arrange the blocks so you don't have to check them all!  Only the blocks in a very narrow coordinate range can possibly be collisions, so make sure you can access blocks by range *quickly*.